# DC motor set to 0.25 RPM pulling -5 Amps at nearly 20% torque - Why the heck is it doing this?

Tags: dc-motor, encoder, plc, vfd

Drive controlling the motor: PowerFlex DC Drive, 460 VAC, 3 PH, 27 Amps, 15 HP/11 kW, Regen, IP20, NEMA/UL Type Open, No HIM (Blank Plate), User Manual, No Communication Module, A Frame

Motor in question: 15 HP, 500 VDC, 25.4 AMPS, 1750 RPM (BASE), CCW Rotation

The scenario: A spinpump motor is fluctuating in RPM when set to 0.25 RPM. It fluctuates in a pattern from 0.19 RPM to 0.29 RPM. The motor for some reason, is pulling -4.33 Amps and around -17% torque. If set to 2 RPM, the current becomes around 1 Amp positive, and 4% of torque.

I have no idea how to explain this phenomena. Any help would be appreciated. [image]

Comment: Is this a scenario that was working before, and now does not?  Or is trying to run at 0.25 RPM a new scenario that you have not tried before?

Comment: Is it possible that the load is driving the pump for part or all of the cycle?

Comment: Are you below the minimum speed of the motor?

Comment: you're trying to run an induction motor at less than 1% RPM?

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica It has been a standard for the operators of this machine to run it in ideal at this RPM, but historically I have been told it has had fluctuations. However, I checked its trend lines a couple months back and it was holding steady around 0.25.

Comment: @Gil I checked the drive executive and the minimum speed is set to 0.

Comment: Is there a gearbox on the motor?  If so, is the 0.25 RPM value the speed of the motor or the speed of the gearbox output?

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica Yes, I believe there is a gearbox. For instance, right now, drive executive is reading that the motor is at 674 RPM, but the sensor speed feedback is reading 21.5 RPM for the Spin Pump. 

However, the current being read is from the motor arm current.

Comment: @JasenСлаваУкраїні After further investigation, it seems that there is a gearbox being driven by the motor. Right now it is a 674 RPM/21.5 RPM Ratio, which is around 31.3/1 ratio.

Comment: When you say that you are running the motor at 0.25 RPM, is that 0.25 RPM motor speed, or is it 0.25 RPM pump speed, which is really 7.84 RPM motor speed?

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica It is 0.25 RPM pump speed, which is 7.84 RPM Speed. Yes, that is correct. I did not factor in the possibility of the gearbox when I asked my question.

Comment: Now that you know this, what is Drive Executive telling you that the motor speed is doing when you are trying to run the pump at 0.25 RPM?

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica I am not sure. I will have to wait until the machine is idle again. It will be very interesting to see what speed I am getting. 

 But, from what I know, the speed should be increasing and then decreasing, because the belt of the spin pump was slowing down and then ramping back up over and over again.